# Loading a SNAP dataset into torch_geometric.data.Data object

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric, snap, gnn, stanford-snap

I am trying to load a SNAP dataset (ego-facebook for now) into a `torch_geometric.data.Data` object. I am having issues.

1. Is there any standard library/method to load SNAP dataset into a `torch_geometric.data.Data` object?
2. I tried using `torch_geometric.datasets.SNAPDataset`. It gives me a storage of 10 Data. How can I merge the `Data` into one object so that I could generate one `Networkx` object?
3. I tried making the Data by adding each edge. Later, I wanted to use `torch_geometric.transforms.RandomNodeSplit` to generate the masks. But it did not add any mask. I figured `RandomNodeSplit` goes over `data.node_stores`. In this case, I didn't have any `node_stores` in my `Data` object. What is the correct way to make a Data object and add nodes/edges to it so that it is consistent with `torch_geometric` style?